# How do I enter an arbitrary Unicode code point into my document?

Tags: unicode

I want to enter a GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA (U+0391) into my LaTeX document. I do not want a LATIN CAPITAL A. How do I do this?

Answer (score 33):

```
\symbol{"0391} % hex
\symbol{913}   % dec
\symbol{'1621} % oct
```

You need a true Unicode TeX engine (XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) to get proper glyphs.

Full example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}

Γ
\symbol{"0393} % hex
\symbol{915}   % dec
\symbol{'1623} % oct

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also possible notation is ^^^^0391. It is preferable for those languages where double qoute is declared to be active symbol.

Comment: @Igor: Sure. If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, it is better to use `ö` directly than `\"o`, or `"o` with `polyglossia` etc.

Comment: it depends! ö can be broken if you ocassinally save your file in an encoding different from utf8.

Comment: @Igor: Well, we are talking about Unicode only TeX engines: XeTeX and LuaTeX. You can't get U+0391 in pdfTeX engine directly. Never use an encoding other than UTF-8 in XeTeX and LuaTeX, although possible.