# XeLaTeX / XeTeX -- fontspec and ornaments/dingbats

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I would like to know if it is possible to use the ornaments contained in a font like Minion Pro from Adobe. I'm using XeLaTeX and fontspec (or mathspec), but I don't find information on ornaments in the guide.

Comment: Did you look at [How can I access a specific glyph in LuaLaTex/fontspec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98188/)? It's LuaLaTeX oriented, but the method outlined in one of the answers should work well.

Comment: I'd say this is a duplicate of that^ question. I added an answer to the latter that [describes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114383/7993) one of several possible ways of finding and using such ornaments.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}

\Huge\char"E0BB\char"E0BC\char"E0BD\char"E0BE\char"E0BF

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very ... concise, as usual ;-)