# How to Use Goudy Initialen in Lettrine

Tags: fonts, fontspec, typography, drop-cap, lettrine

How can I use the Goudy Initialen font with Lettrine for the first drop letter of a paragraph? I can't understand from the documentation how to  use LettrineFontHook or LettrineFont to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague without an [MWE,](http://goo.gl/5XLQU) but if the problem is what I think it is, the answer would be something like:

```
\documentclass[DIV=9,paper=a5,pagesize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,blindtext,lettrine}

\newfontfamily\goudy[Scale=6]{Goudy Initialen}
\renewcommand*{\LettrineFont}{\goudy}

\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=4]{L}{orem ipsum}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

This uses the TrueType version of the font, as [provided](http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/steffmann/index.htm) by Dieter Steffmann himself. I think someone did a conversion to Type1 once, for use with pdfTeX, but since you seem to be on Xe/LuaTeX, you might as well use the original version.

Comment: Yes it was that simple. I missed                     \newfontfamily\goudy[Scale=6]{Goudy Initialen}"                  as the first statement. Thanks

Comment: @ramonskovitch: glad to hear that. If you consider [your questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116345) answered, don't forget to mark the answer you like best as [›accepted‹.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/someone-answers) If you change your mind later on, or an even better answer is posted, you can still change it.