# How can I access Garamond Premier Pro's straight "quotedbl/quotesingle" using lualatex?

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

Idea (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114383/74259)): I use `\symbol{idx}`, where idx is the glyphs index.

To determine these two glyphs' indexes I had a look into `...texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otf\garamondpremrpro.lua` and verified the result using fontforge as well as MS Word. All three report, that "34" and "39" should be the correct indexes - please see the following screenshots:

[image: garamondpremrpro.lua]

[image: Fontforge Screenshot]

[image: MS Word is able to access the correct glyphs]

I also verified the general idea using the index of "blacksquare" (9632): Although the black square is set correctly, the quotedbl/quotesingle do not show up using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}

\newcommand{\blackSquare}{\symbol{9632}} %<-- works fine
\newcommand{\straightQuoteDbl}{\symbol{34}} %<-- does not work
\newcommand{\straightQuoteSingle}{\symbol{39}} %<-- does not work

\begin{document}

{\straightQuoteDbl}Hello World! \blackSquare\straightQuoteDbl

{\straightQuoteSingle}Hello World! \blackSquare\straightQuoteSingle

\end{document}
```

The code produces the following output:

[image]

Both quotes clearly differ from the results MS Word produces (see above).

```
System environment: Win 7 Pro 64-bit
TeX-Environment: texlive 2014 (frozen)
Font: Garamond Premier Pro Version 2.0.104
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[RawFeature={-tlig}]` or, to affect only parts of the document, `\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={-tlig}}`

Comment: @Thérèse: Thanks a lot - it works perfectly: `\newcommand{\straightQuoteSingle}{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={-tlig}}\symbol{39}}`. You should (re)write this solution into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly quotes appear because TeX ligatures are on by default in recent versions of `fontspec`.  If your document consists of code only, you can disable TeX ligatures with `\setmainfont`, this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[RawFeature=-tlig]
\newcommand{\blackSquare}{\symbol{9632}}
\begin{document}
"Hello World! \blackSquare"
\end{document}
```

Or, as egreg suggests, you can put `\defaultfontfeatures{}` in the preamble; that would affect Garamond and any other font used in the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature=-tlig}% put before specific fonts to affect them all
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newcommand{\blackSquare}{\symbol{9632}}
\begin{document}
"Hello World! \blackSquare"
\end{document}
```

If you want straight quotes in only part of the document, use this approach:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newcommand{\blackSquare}{\symbol{9632}}
\begin{document}
``Hello, beautiful World!''

{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-tlig}"Hello World! \blackSquare"}
\end{document}
```

(You can define a macro to shorten that if you like.)

Or you can disable TeX ligatures globally, as in the two examples, and type real “, ”, ‘, ’, –, and — into your source when you need them.

Comment: Or with `\defaultfontfeatures{}` before defining the fonts.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: Maybe you should mention csquotes

Comment: @MaxNoe I’ve never had reason to use `csquotes` in my work, so I’m not the right person to explain how it would help here. Maybe you should add a second answer?

Comment: Did you try it out? I might bet you had a reason :D I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `csquotes` to define a quoting style which uses these straight quotes:

The `\DeclareQuoteStyle` command has 5 positional arguments, the name for the style, opening and closing marks for both outer and inner quotes:

You can then use the style with `\setquotestyle{<name>}`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}               

\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{straight}%
{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-tlig}\symbol{34}}}%
{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-tlig}\symbol{34}}}%
{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-tlig}\symbol{39}}}%
{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=-tlig}\symbol{39}}}     

\setquotestyle{straight}

\begin{document}
John said: \enquote{Harry said \enquote{Hello World!} yesterday}.
\end{document}
```

The extra curly braces are needed to make the change in fontfeatures local to the quotation mark only.

This is the result:
[image: result]

Comment: I defined this: `\newcommand{\straightQuote}[1]{{\setquotestyle{straight}\enquote{#1}}}` and use it like this: `John said: \straightQuote{Harry said \enquote{Hello World!} yesterday}.`

Comment: That's a nice addition!

Comment: You should add a star to the new command to allow for multi paragraph arguments