# Enter single unicode code point in (dvi)latex and latin1 input

Tags: unicode, dvi-mode

For various reasons, I'm stuck with (dvi)latex and inputencoding latin1. I still want to enter unicode codepoints (I have the hex/decimal numbers ready).

I have seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32514/24158 but this does not seem to work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\symbol{324}
\end{document}
```

I just get some `! Bad character code (324).`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\symbol{324}` can only take values in the 8-bit range and refers directly to the underlying font not going through latex's encoding mechanisms.

Any symbol for which there is support in `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` will have a mapping from the Unicode number to a TeX definition in the utf8 files in the base distribution, or you can directly code something. so Unicode 324 is `LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH ACUTE` so you can use `\'{n}`  which corresponds to this line in `utf8enc.dfu` in the base latex distribution

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0144}{\@tabacckludge'n}
```

decimal 324 being hex 144

---

If you don't want to look up the definitions in the file, you can load the file with a local definition that removes the utf8 decoding part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\def\DeclareUnicodeCharacter#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\csname ut-#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\UseUnicodeCharacter#1{\csname ut-#1\endcsname}

\makeatletter\input{utf8enc.dfu}\makeatother
\begin{document}

aaaa\UseUnicodeCharacter{0144}bbb

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: The interesting question is: Can I use the tables in the base distribution? Like how can I use that `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0144}{\@tabacckludge'n}` and have something like a `\InsertUnicode{0144}` which goes through those tables and finally does the `\@tabacckludge'n`?  Using `\'{n}` is an option for individual characters, but I would prefer to be able to enter unicode codepoints, because those are in my sources.

Comment: @Elrond see updated code

Answer (score 3):

Input the relevant file, for instance `t1enc.dfu` for the characters obtainable in the T1 encoding. Just assign a suitable definition to `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\loadencoding}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\DeclareUnicodeCharacter##1##2{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname uni\number"##1\endcsname
      {{\fontencoding{#1}\selectfont##2}}}
  \makeatletter
  \lowercase{\input{#1enc.dfu}}%
  \endgroup}
\newcommand\unisymbol[1]{\csname uni\number#1\endcsname}

\loadencoding{T1}
\loadencoding{T2A}


\begin{document}
\unisymbol{324} \unisymbol{"0144} \unisymbol{"0428}
\end{document}
```

This will print

> ń ń Ш