# How do I enter an arbitrary Unicode code point, with pdfTeX?

Tags: pdftex, symbols, unicode

I've just found

[How do I enter an arbitrary Unicode code point into my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/how-do-i-enter-an-arbitrary-unicode-code-point-into-my-document)

but I want to do the same with pdfTeX, not LuaTeX. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume, the Unicode character is given as four hexadecimal digits (or eight hexadecimal digits for a surrogate pair). Then macro `\uni` performs the following steps:

- First the hex string is extended to eight hexadecimal digits for a full hexadecimal representation of a Unicode character in encoding `UTF-32BE`.
- `\pdfunescapehex` converts the hexadecimal digits to the four bytes in encoding `UTF-32BE`.
- Package `stringenc` converts from `UTF-32BE` to `UTF-8`.
- `\scantokens` is used to convert the string of inactive characters (category code 12/other) to active characters, needed for encoding `utf8` of package `inputenc`.
- Since the definition is fragile, the macro is made robust by `\DeclareRobustCommand`.
- Additionally, support for `hyperref` is added, so that the defined macro `\uni` can be used in bookmarks.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{stringenc}
\newcommand*{\uni}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\uni}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \StringEncodingConvert\x{%
      \pdfunescapehex{%
        00%
        \ifnum"#1<"100000 0\fi
        \ifnum"#1<"10000 0\fi
        \ifnum"#1<"1000 0\fi
        \ifnum"#1<"100 0\fi
        \ifnum"#1<"10 0\fi
        #1%
      }%
    }{utf32be}{utf8}%
    \everyeof{\noexpand}%
    \endlinechar=-1 %
  \edef\x{%
    \endgroup
    \scantokens\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\x}%
    }%
  }\x
}

% hyperref support
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\uni#1{\unichar{"#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Musical note \uni{266A} in title}
Symbols: \uni{266A}, \uni{B1}, \uni{20AC}, \uni{DF}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: For what it's worth, I just enter the Unicode character directly into my document. There's no general reason to keep everything in ASCII, although you may have specific requirements otherwise.