# Displaying Arbitrary Unicode Characters under Plain TeX with pdfTeX

Tags: unicode, plain-tex

I wish to enter arbitrary Unicode characters while writing in Plain TeX using the pdfTeX engine. How may this be achieved? I have already referred to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268069/how-do-i-enter-an-arbitrary-unicode-code-point-with-pdftex), but the solution assumes the use of LaTeX, whereas I am using Plain TeX. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just use a Unicode engine with a Unicode font and enter it directly.

Comment: Is there a reason for only considering pdfTeX but not XeTeX or LuaTeX?

Comment: pdftex has no support for unicode, it is possible to emulate certain aspects of Unicode encodings in the macro layer but plain tex has no such macros you could input a version of the latex macros into plain tex, but that is more or less equivalent to using latex, which you say you do not want to do.

Comment: A starting point is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163852/how-to-input-accents-in-plaintex-with-utf-8-encoding but you need to find yourself the fonts for the needed characters.

Answer (score 4):

With LuaTeX and XeTeX you get Unicode support for free.

```
\ifdefined\directlua
  \input luaotfload.sty
\fi

\font\tenrm="CMU Serif"
\rm

¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ª « ¬ ­ ® ¯ ° ± ² ³ ´ µ ¶ · ¸ ¹ º »

¼ ½ ¾ ¿ À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö

× Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ

ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: When I try this, I get the error: `Font \tenrm=CMU Serif not loadable: metric data not found or bad.`