# How to typset the Meitei Script in LaTeX and Overleaf?

Tags: fontspec, unicode, overleaf

I am trying to write a language script which is represented by the UTF-16 code format: the Meitei script, occupying U+ABC0 to U+ABFF in the Unicode block. All i could find in the internet is related to UTF-8 or some special characters. How can I write the language script in LaTeX or Overleaf? Thanks.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.) Overleaf converts all plain text files to UTF-8. Which language are you writing, by the way? You can contact support@overleaf.com if you have a specific project there to debug.

Comment: @LianTzeLim The one I am trying to write has the code points range: U+ABC0 to U+ABFF in the Unicode block.

Comment: Would that be the Meitei script or Meetei Mayek? You're in luck, Noto Sans Meetei Mayek is available on Overleaf, and so you can use XeLaTeX. I'll follow up with a quick answer and example; it would be great if you can edit your question to mention that you're specifically looking to typeset Meetei Mayek.

Comment: @LianTzeLim yes it is. Thanks a lot. If possible, please give an example of writing any unicode characters (UTF-8 or UTF-16) using the the code-points or hex code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overleaf converts plain text files to UTF-8. In this case the question is about typesetting the [Meitei script (Meetei Mayek)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meitei_script): this can be done using XeLaTeX, the `fontspec` package, and a suitable font e.g. [Google Noto Sans Meetei Mayek](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-mtei).

(You would also need to have this font installed on your computer to view the Meitei glyphs in the example below and in the Overleaf editor panel.)

A small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

This is some normal English text in Latin script. The next paragraph is Meitei:

{\fontspec{Noto Sans Meetei Mayek}
ꯀ ꯁ ꯂ ꯃ ꯄ ꯅ
\symbol{"ABC6}
}

Here we're back to English.
\end{document}
```

[image: Typesetting Meetei Mayek with XeLaTeX+fontspec]

This example code needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. On Overleaf, you can click on the Overleaf menu icon above the file list panel, and then set "Compiler" to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32514/226) for more examples of entering characters by hexadecimal, decimal or octal code points.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the symbol part and its working. But I couldn't write the Noto Sans font. I treid installing the font in my system, and tried typing some characters. Its typing only Roman characters.

Comment: Do you mean you want to type the Meitei characters from your keyboard? You may need a specific input method to do that, which is beyond the scope of LaTeX, tex.sx and Overleaf... I copied the characters from Wikipedia so I didn't do any typing.

Comment: Hi Lim, I have been trying to run the above code in overleaf. Till now, I have been compling with pdfLatex compiler. But when I changed to XeLatex compiler, it keeps on showing timeout. And when I changed to LuaLatex compiler, all the refrences cite, table and figures are showing error. And the symbols are also not showing at all. I did't get timeout in LuaLatex. Could youplease guide me on how to fix this?

Comment: You can contact support@overleaf.com to let us know your project's URL, so that we can have a look at the project directly.