# Unicode Character/Symbol in Lua(La)TeX

Tags: luatex, unicode

I am trying to print a specific unicode character in LuaLaTeX using

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \char"2605 \symbol{"2605"} ^^^^2605
\end{document}
```

However, none of these prints the black star (unicode 2605).  The first two commands show nothing while the last one prints a right double quotation mark.  Help.

Comment: The second `"` in `"2605` is wrong. And the log says: `There is no ★ (U+2605) in font [lmroman10-regular]`. You need a font that contains that glyph.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/how-do-i-enter-an-arbitrary-unicode-code-point-into-my-document?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How, then, is $\blackstar$ (amssymb) created?

Comment: classic tex math fonts are not in unicode encoding, there are multiple fonts and each character is in the range 0-127

Answer (score 5):

Works with one of the fonts from http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/fontsupport.htm

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
   \char"2605 \symbol{"2605} ^^^^2605
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I said in the comment above, the second `"` in `"2605"` is wrong.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you

Comment: Using fontspec and setting the font to FiraSans-Regular also does not display this character even though the character is showing in the character map.

Comment: @TroyHenderson don't trust the character map (if you mean e.g. the windows one) it often fills missing characters with glyphs from other fonts.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.